# Is there a way to realize two finger dragging and three finger rolling?

Tags: macos, trackpad, multi-touch

Three finger is more dull than the two finger, which is more suitable for simple up and down scroll sliding, while the two finger occupy less area of the touch panel, and the resistance during sliding is less than the three finger, which is more suitable for more complex drag actions. Is there any way to exchange the default three finger drag and two finger scroll?

Comment: Have you tried Better Touch Tool?

Comment: @Gilby I've tried BTT. But as Brandon Lewis answered, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. The only thing that might theoretically make that possible is BetterTouchTool, but at the moment, it cannot remap scrolling and screen-swapping.

Comment: Thanks! I tried BTT as you suggested. Actually it does able to remap scolling and I made a three finger scrolling profile. Unfortunately, it scrolls pixel by pixel